# how to solve this in python (for and while loops)?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Here's my question:
Output the following to represent:

Welcome student #1, your ticket is #1001

Welcome student #2, your ticket is #1002

….

Welcome student #10, your ticket is #1010

and this is what I have so far:

```
#--RAFFLE TICKETS--#
for i in range(1001,1011):  #since 1001 is inclusive and 1011 is exclusive 
    for j in range(1,11):
        print("Welcome student #",j,"your ticket is #"+str(i))
    break
```

but I can't get the numbers of tickets to go up to 10. I need this with both (for and while loops). Thanks in advance for any help given!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print ( "Welcome student #", i ,"your ticket is #" , 1000+i)
```

Using a while loop:

```
i=1   
while i<=10:
    print ( "Welcome student #", i ,"your ticket is #" , 1000+i)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need nested loops?

```
>>> for i in range(1, 11):
...     print('Welcome student # {} your ticket is #10{:02d}'.format(i, i))
...     
Welcome student # 1 your ticket is #1001
Welcome student # 2 your ticket is #1002
Welcome student # 3 your ticket is #1003
Welcome student # 4 your ticket is #1004
Welcome student # 5 your ticket is #1005
Welcome student # 6 your ticket is #1006
Welcome student # 7 your ticket is #1007
Welcome student # 8 your ticket is #1008
Welcome student # 9 your ticket is #1009
Welcome student # 10 your ticket is #1010
```

Comment: it seems a bit silly to have a `format` call inside a `format` call like this. Why not put `:02d` in the second set of brackets to do it all at once?

Comment: @Blckknght different strokes for different folks; but its probably more obvious with the embedded format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
for i in range(1001,1011):
     print("Welcome student #"+str(i-1000) + " your ticket is #"+str(i))
```

Or, as a while loop:

```
value = 1001
while value<1011:
    print("Welcome student #"+str(value-1000)+ "your ticket is #"+str(value))
    value+=1
```

Comment: what about using a while-loop?

Comment: I believe a while loop would be unnecessary, but Ill add it in.

Comment: the reason I asked for a while-loop is because I have to do the same problem using both loops. but thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dictionary:

```
>>> a = range(1001,1011)
>>> b = {x:a[x] for x in range(len(a))}
>>> for key, val in b.items():
        print ("Welcome student #"+ str(key+1) + " your ticket is #"+str(val))
```

Welcome student #1 your ticket is #1001
Welcome student #2 your ticket is #1002
Welcome student #3 your ticket is #1003
Welcome student #4 your ticket is #1004
Welcome student #5 your ticket is #1005
Welcome student #6 your ticket is #1006
Welcome student #7 your ticket is #1007
Welcome student #8 your ticket is #1008
Welcome student #9 your ticket is #1009
Welcome student #10 your ticket is #1010